# loginredirect display specific user view

Tags: php, authentication

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'view'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
        'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
        'authorize'=>array('Controller')
    )
);
```

When I use index instead of view it works, but when I use view I get an error:

```
invalid user
Error: The requested address '/skill_application/users/view' was not found on this server.
```

When a user logs in I want it to redirect to the users view. How can give the id to the view?